# How to read json

Tags: javascript, json, jsonreader

I have following JSON object.

```
{"feed":[
    {"news":
      {"adopted_from":null,"user_id":null,"description":"this is test","id":2}
   },
   {"news":
     {"adopted_from":null,"user_id":null,"description":"like unlike done","id":1}
    }
]}
```

I want to retrieve the **id** of news. I tried in many different ways (e.g. `feed[0].news.id`, `feed.news.id`, `feed[[0].news.id]`) but could not access the value. Can anyone help me how can I access it using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied and pasted your JSON from above and tried the following and it works just fine:

```
    var data = {"feed":[{"news":{"adopted_from":null,"user_id":null,"description":"this is test","id":2}},{"news":{"adopted_from":null,"user_id":null,"description":"like unlike done","id":1}}]};
    // alert the first news id
    alert(data.feed[0].news.id);
```

It gets the id from the first `news` object from the array as intended.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
var f = {"feed":[{"news":{"adopted_from":null,"user_id":null,"description":"this is test","id":2}},{"news":{"adopted_from":null,"user_id":null,"description":"like unlike done","id":1}}]}
alert( f.feed[0].news.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var feed = json_decode(yourData)
for(var counter in feed) {
    console.log(feed[counter].news.id);
}
```